How make dimension compatible between an TCN ins Space and a LSTM in Time?
I would like to create a model with a TCN followed by an LSTM. I have some difficulties to understand how to use the dimension of each layer I have.
my data can be viewed in 3D with (Time, space, features). the time can vary and is set to None, the space is fixed to 257 and the features is 1.
the input of the TCN is then (None, 257, 1) and the output is (None, 257, 64) because I extract 64 features.
LSTM in keras is (samples, time steps, and features), then it does not correspond with the output of my TCN layer (Time, space, features).
my question is, How can I reformate my dimensions for both TCN and LSTM to be compatible. TCN should be apply in the space dimension but the LSTM in the Time dimension.
To do that I have first flatten the output of the TCN with give dims (None, 257x64), then I expand a dimension to get 3D (as the input of LSTM need to be) dims = (1, None, 257x64).
I then apply the LSTM layer and I remove the dimension I added to get my correct output for my labels (Time, Features) = (None, Features)
Does this is correct? or am I doing things wrong?
Here the model I have made so far:
import tensorflow as tf
from tcn2 import TCN

SpaceDim = 257
Time = None
Data = [Time,SpaceDim,1]


ip = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(SpaceDim, 1))

TCN0 = TCN(nb_filters=64, kernel_size=3, nb_stacks=1,
         dilations=(1, 2, 4, 8, 16), activation='linear', return_sequences=True, name='tcn0')(ip)

TCN0 = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(TCN0)
TCN0_f = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(TCN0)
TCN1 = tf.keras.backend.expand_dims(TCN0_f, 0)

LSTM0 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(258, return_sequences=True)(TCN1)
LSTM1 = tf.keras.backend.squeeze(LSTM0, 0)

out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(15003)(LSTM1)
model = tf.keras.models.Model(ip, out)

Adamp = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.00001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0,
                                 amsgrad=True)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adamp, metrics=['mse', 'mae'])
model.summary()

The summary give this :
 _________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_3 (InputLayer)        [(None, 257, 1)]          0         
                                                                 
 tcn0 (TCN)                  (None, 257, 64)           111552    
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 257, 64)           0         
                                                                 
 flatten_3 (Flatten)         (None, 16448)             0         
                                                                 
 tf.expand_dims_3 (TFOpLambd  (1, None, 16448)         0         
 a)                                                              
                                                                 
 lstm_1 (LSTM)               (1, None, 258)            17241624  
                                                                 
 tf.compat.v1.squeeze_1 (TFO  (None, 258)              0         
 pLambda)                                                        
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 15003)             3885777   
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 21,238,953
Trainable params: 21,238,953
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________

